# Why do two statement terminators not throw a syntax error?

Tags: php, syntax

I noticed this code:

```
$li = "Hello World";;
```

Why is PHP not throwing a syntax error even though there are two semicolons? Is PHP really this loosely typed?

Ugly.

Comment: Why is there a syntax error? `;` means end of a statement, your first statement is `$li = "Hello World";` , second is empty..

Comment: You do know that C also allows this use of two semicolons? ([Example](http://codepad.org/aab8xg8q))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser has no concept of white space so that's the equivalent of this:

```
$li = "Hello World";
;
```

Which of course is fine, because empty statements are valid syntax. (And no, that's not ugly, unless you make a typo. And typos are always ugly. Although I agree, PHP is very messy.)

Comment: I'd amend that, by saying the second `;` would be interepreted as `noop` and optimized away. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP

Comment: Well, that's what would happen behind the scenes, yeah. Doesn't change what I'm saying, though.

Comment: @ElliotBeonneville haven't said, that you are wrong. just wanted to give the extra information.